# Get value of JSON array where key has multiple entries

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array that looks roughly like this:

```
HotelInformationResponse
-    HotelSummary
--   name = "Way Hotel"
-    HotelImages
--   HotelImage
---  0
---- url = "something"
---  1
---- url = "something"
---  2
---- url = "something"
---  3
---- url = "something"
```

I'm trying to get the value of HotelImages -> HotelImage -> 0 -> url

I know how to do it for HotelSummary -> name  like so:

`var hotelname = results.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary.name;
 $('#json_name').append(hotelname);`

But can't figure out how to do this when a key has multiple sub keys which aren't names?

I tried like this:

`var main_pic = results.HotelInformationResponse.HotelImage.['0'].url;
    $('#main_pic').attr('img', main_pic);`

Which probably doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `results.HotelInformationResponse.HotelImages.HotelImage[0].url`

Comment: wow, I tried that before but my image didn't change so I assumed it didn't work, turns out the image change thing itself didn't work. Thanks @blex !

Comment: Please post your answer as "answer" so user327685 can accept it and people don't strumble upon this anymore.